# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException, but bean is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am attempting to get the configurations into Spring Boot using Java based config instead of XML config from this blog post:
http://blog.novoj.net/2012/03/27/combining-custom-annotations-for-securing-methods-with-spring-security/

I am getting the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postAuthorizeAdvisor' defined in class path resource [test/project/security/aop/AopSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this 
>       dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

The following is the class that contains these bean definitions:

```
@Configuration
public class AopSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityInterceptor methodSecurityInterceptor(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        MethodSecurityInterceptor msi = new MethodSecurityInterceptor();
        msi.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        msi.setValidateConfigAttributes(false);

        MethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();

        ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory factory = new ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory(handler);
        ExperimentalPrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource metadataSource = new ExperimentalPrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource(factory);
        msi.setSecurityMetadataSource(metadataSource);

        ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice advice = new ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
        advice.setExpressionHandler(handler);
        AccessDecisionVoter<?> voter = new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(advice);
        AccessDecisionManager manager = new AffirmativeBased(Collections.singletonList(voter));
        msi.setAccessDecisionManager(manager);

        return msi;
    }

    @Bean
    public Advisor preAuthorizeAdvisor(MethodSecurityInterceptor methodSecurityInterceptor) {
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression("execution(@(@org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize *) * *.* (..))");
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, methodSecurityInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public Advisor preFilterAdvisor(MethodSecurityInterceptor methodSecurityInterceptor) {
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression("execution(@(@org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreFilter *) * *.* (..))");
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, methodSecurityInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public Advisor postAuthorizeAdvisor(MethodSecurityInterceptor methodSecurityInterceptor) {
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression("execution(@(@org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PostAuthorize *) * *.* (..))");
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, methodSecurityInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public Advisor postFilterAdvisor(MethodSecurityInterceptor methodSecurityInterceptor) {
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression("execution(@(@org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PostFilter *) * *.* (..))");
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, methodSecurityInterceptor);
    }
}
```

Is there a reason why the MethodSecurityInterceptor bean is not found?

**Edit**

This is the full stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nes
ted exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aopSecurityConfiguration' defined in file [C:\test\test-project\build\classes\main\test\project
\security\aop\AopSecurityConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postF
ilterAdvisor' defined in class path resource [test/project/security/aop/AopSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springf
ramework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor] found for 
dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionEx
ception: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire can
didate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at test.project.Application.main(Application.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aopSecurityConfiguration' defined in file [C:\test\test-project\build\classes\main\test\project\secur
ity\aop\AopSecurityConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postFilterA
dvisor' defined in class path resource [test/project/security/aop/AopSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframewo
rk.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor] found for depend
ency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionExceptio
n: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
 for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:85)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:243)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:466)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'postFilterAdvisor' defined in class path resource [test/project/security/aop/AopSecurityConf
iguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor]: : No qualify
ing bean of type [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dep
endency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopa
lliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:85)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:324)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.getEarlyBeanReference(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:232)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getEarlyBeanReference(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:819)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:240)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:85)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:324)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.getEarlyBeanReference(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:232)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getEarlyBeanReference(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:819)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:240)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:85)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:324)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor] found for d
ependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 95 common frames omitted
```

**Edit**

I was able to fix this issue by removing my implementation of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. This removed my configuration for AuthenticationManagerBuilder and HttpSecurity.

For the authentication manager it is my understanding that I needed to create an AuthenticationProvider for handling the authentication of users so I used DaoAuthenticationProvider and InMemoryUserDetailsManager to create a simple provider. This was previously done using the AuthenticationManagerBuilder#inMemoryAuthentication.

I am not sure how I need to setup an instance of HttpSecurity so that I can use form login, which I was able to do with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

Comment: Is it only the postAuthorizeAdvisor method that it is complaining about? try commenting this method out and running the program again to see if it complains about the other methods?

Comment: Once you've commented out that method then if the other methods also cause similar exceptions then try adding @Autowired to the MethodSecurityInterceptor argument in your postAuthorizeAdvisor method to wire in the MethodSecurityInterceptor bean

Comment: I commented out each of the advisor methods and they all gave similar exceptions. I then tried to put the Autowired annotation on the MethodSecurityInterceptor argument, but I received an error indicating that it is not allowed there. So I tried putting it on the advisor method instead and I received the same exception.

Comment: Are you sure you that is the full stack trace? There is some post processing done on the MethodSecurityInterceptor bean that checks the security data store and access decision manager. If either of those are bad you will get an exception creating the bean.

Comment: No, it was not the full stacktrace, I trimmed it down to the part that I thought was relevant. I have updated the post to include the full stacktrace. Also the method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how to correct this, not entirely sure why this works, but it does. I removed the AopSecurityConfiguration class and moved the methodSecurityInterceptor method to my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation and removed the authenticationManager argument. In the method I am now calling the authenticationManager method of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

Doing this has allowed me to create custom Pre/PostAuthorize annotated annotations that I can and/or the annotations using the RulesRelation annotation.

Not sure what the pointcut advisors described on the original blog were needed for, maybe that was something that was required for a previous version but no long is?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put `@Autowired` annotation at top of **each** of the methods where `methodSecurityInterceptor` is used.

For example:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public Advisor postAuthorizeAdvisor(MethodSecurityInterceptor methodSecurityInterceptor) {
    AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
    pointcut.setExpression("execution(@(@org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PostAuthorize *) * *.* (..))");
    return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, methodSecurityInterceptor);
}
```

Comment: @smoggers suggested this in the comments section of the question. When I did so I received the same exception as when I did not have the Autowired annotations. Also I use a similar pattern elsewhere without the Autowired annotation and it works correctly. I found that once I removed the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation I had defined I was able to get past this issue (I still don't understand why that worked), but that introduced its own set of issues.